# How to use onLongClick to Save Images in WebView?

Tags: android, webview

How to implement `onLongClick` to save Images displayed in `WebView`?

Comment: See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159247/how-to-save-images-displayed-in-webview and try it inside onlongclick method

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963164/context-menu-for-image-saving-in-an-android-webview).

Comment: can u give a code sample?
m new to it & its a bit difficult...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159247/how-to-save-images-displayed-in-webview

Comment: @Amit Vaghela
thats not what I want

Comment: show what you have tried.